# Encryption + Decryption with OpenSSL slow rate when tested with bigger files

Tags: c, file, encryption, openssl

I just coded two C applications, one to encrypt and another to decrypt files.

The code for file manipulation during encryption+decryption was copied/pasted from [OpenSSL site](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/crypto/EVP_EncryptInit.html#EXAMPLES) and changed to use AES-GCM

It works like a charm! The thing is

- for a 500MB file, the cipher rate is 80MB/s
- for a 10000MB file, the cipher rate goes down to 22MB/s

I should be nearly constant. If the rate is around 80MB/s for 500MB file, that's the rate I should get for a 10GB file (a little less, maybe, but not THAT much!).

As I increase the file size, the cipher rate keeps decreasing.

Could it be an issue with the file manipulation? Maybe something related to the memory usage? Am I doing something wrong?

Here is the code I'm actually using:

```
const EVP_CIPHER *cipher;
unsigned char inbuf[1024], outbuf[1024 + EVP_MAX_BLOCK_LENGTH];
int inlen, outlen;
/* Initialize cipher*/
cipher = EVP_aes_256_gcm (); // AES in Galois Counter Mode
EVP_CIPHER_CTX *encCTX = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();
EVP_CipherInit_ex(encCTX, cipher, NULL, key, iv, 1); // 1 for encrypt, 0 for decrypt

/* Loop loading file chunks and cipher it*/
for(;;) {
    inlen = fread(inbuf, 1, 1024, sourceFilePointer);
    if(inlen <= 0) break;
    if(!EVP_CipherUpdate(encCTX, outbuf, &outlen, inbuf, inlen)) {
        /* Error */
        EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(encCTX);
        printf("Error while updating ciphered file \n");
        free(key);
        free(targetFilename);
        return 0;
    }
    fwrite(outbuf, 1, outlen, outputFilePointer);
}

/* Finish the cipher*/
if(!EVP_CipherFinal_ex(encCTX, outbuf, &outlen)) {
    /* Error */
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(encCTX);
    printf("Error while finalizing cipher \n");
    free(key);
    free(targetFilename);
    return 0;
}
fwrite(outbuf, 1, outlen, outputFilePointer);

EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl (encCTX, EVP_CTRL_GCM_GET_TAG, TAG_SIZE, tag);
EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(encCTX);
fclose(outputFilePointer);
```

UPDATE: I commented out the entire cipher update section `EVP_CipherUpdate(encCTX, outbuf, &outlen, inbuf, inlen)` and replaced `fwrite(outbuf, 1, outlen, outputFilePointer)` with `fwrite(inbuf, 1, inlen, outputFilePointer)` as suggested in the comments to test if the file copy rate was constant for different file sizes. After testing a few times with different file sizes the IO rate proved to be constant.

Comment: Lower results for bigger files, may be related with caching. It's just a guess.

Comment: How fast does rewriting the file without encrypting it take?

Comment: sorry, I didn't get it... what did you mean by rewriting the file without encrypting?

Comment: @vianna77 Comment out your call to `EVP_CipherUpdate`, and replace `fwrite(outbuf, 1, outlen, outputFilePointer)` with `fwrite(inbuf, 1, inlen, outputFilePointer)` so all your code does is make an unencrypted copy of the file.  If *that* goes slower with larger files, the problem is in the copying, and if that doesn't go slower with larger files, the problem is in the encryption.

Comment: Great idea! thank you! I will do that and check what happens. I'm at home now, but as soon I get back to work, I will make that test.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I just finished the copy experiment... took the time 3 times for files with 500MB, 1GB and 10GB... it was linear, maintaining the rate.

Comment: So, the IO rate *without* encryption is constant?  And doesn't get slower?  Can you try a different cipher, maybe something really simple like `EVP_enc_null()`?  (It's hard to be simpler than that - `EVP_enc_null()` doesn't actually do *any* encryption...)

Comment: Yep, the IO rate without encryption is constant and doesn't get any slower with bigger files. I will try the EVP_enc_null.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112950/discussion-between-vianna77-and-andrew-henle).

Comment: @vianna77 - when you find an answer, please provide it. Maybe its the `fwrite(inbuf, 1, inlen, outputFilePointer)`? I''ll update OpenSSL's wiki accordingly. Also, you might want to try `mmap` and friends to avoid extra copies from the file system to memory. Just map a view of the view and work with it directly.

Comment: @jww , I already made the code copy the stream from IN to OUT without any encryption and also changed the cipher to `EVP_enc_null()` and both cases maintain a constant rate of read/write for very different file sizes. In practical terms, I will use `EVP_aes_256_gcm` to encrypt only sensitive files, making the payload to be encrypted somewhat small. Other people will probably have to deal with that issue.